# CakePHP-3.0 plugin form validation error message and entered data

Tags: cakephp, plugins, cakephp-3.0

I have created a CommentManager plugin for adding comments in my posts. Adding the comment form in `Posts/view.ctp` file and the comment form action is redirecting to `CommentManager/Comments/add`.

The comments are saving properly but when saving empty form, that doesn't shows the validation error messages which i have written in `CommentsTable` and also the entered data has gone from the form.

**CommentManager/src/Controller/CommentsController/add**

```
public function add()
{
    $ccomment = $this->Comments->newEntity($this->request->data);
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $newData = ['post_id' => $this->request->params['pass'][0]];
        $ccomment = $this->Comments->patchEntity($ccomment, $newData);

        if ($this->Comments->save($ccomment)) {
            $this->Flash->success('The comment has been saved.');
            return $this->redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error('The comment could not be saved. Please, try again.');
        }
    }
    $this->set(compact('ccomment'));        
    return $this->redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
}
```

**CommentManager/src/Model/Table/CommentsTable**

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator) {
    return $validator
        ->notEmpty('body', 'Body contents required.')
        ->notEmpty('email', 'An email is required.')
        ->add('email', [
            'format' => [
                'rule' => [
                    'custom',
                    '/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/'
                ],
                'message' => 'Enter a valid email.'
            ]
        ]);
}
```

**src/Template/Posts/view.ctp**

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('Back', ['action' => 'index']) ?>
<?php echo $this->element('check_login'); ?>
<br/>
<?php $img_path = DS.'webroot'.DS.'images'.DS.$post->image; ?>
<img src="<?php echo empty($post->image)?'':$img_path; ?>">
<h2><?php echo $post->title; ?></h2>
<p><?php echo $post->body; ?></p>
<p><small><?php echo $post->created->format('d M Y'); ?></small></p>


<h3>Comments:</h3>
<?php foreach ($comments as $comment) { ?>
    <p><?php echo $comment->body; ?></p>        
<?php } ?>

<?php
echo $this->Form->create(null, ['url' => ['plugin' => 'CommentManager', 'controller' => 'Comments', 'action' => 'add', $post->id]]);
echo $this->Form->input('body', ['type' => 'textarea', 'rows' => '5', 'cols' => '5']);
echo $this->Form->input('email');
echo $this->Form->button('Save');
echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `newEntity()` with an empty array. Inste of

```
$ccomment = $this->Comments->newEntity($this->request->data);
```

Do:

```
$ccomment = $this->Comments->newEntity();
```

And in in the call to `patchEntity()` pass the `$this->request->data`

Comment: Ok but if i will do that then how to add the associated data in the entity. Then i have to modify the $this->request->data.

Comment: Yes, you will have to modify the array before passing it to new entity, or manually change the entity after it has been created.

Comment: The problem was happening because of the reload of the page. I just got two solutions first i can do that with session and the second one with modelless forms. thanks for your help.